# required message shown when none of the fields are filled out

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following code on my web page:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label asp-for="HomePhone" class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
                        <input asp-for="HomePhone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="(___) ___-____" data-slots="_" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="HomePhone" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label asp-for="WorkPhone" class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
                        <input asp-for="WorkPhone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="(___) ___-____" data-slots="_" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="WorkPhone" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label asp-for="CellPhone" class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
                        <input asp-for="CellPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="(___) ___-____" data-slots="_" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="CellPhone" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
    </div>
       <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px"  >
                    <input style="float: right; margin-bottom:20px" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
```

I want the end users to fill out at least one phone number. If they dont fill out any phone number then I want to display a required message
saying that at least one phone number is required. They can fill out all three phone number if they want to. I want this required message to be displayed when the end users click on the
submit button. can the message be displayed as a tooltip or in red color text at the bottom of the text box. Can this be accomplished in JavaScript or jQuery.

Currently, I have something like this on my web page. I have all the three phone number as required:

[image]

I am accomplishing this by making them required in the Model class.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you can use jQuery. You can prepare a function that check the fields. This function will be triggered when you click on the submit button.
If the three field was empty, then the submit will be rejected and the message will be shown. Else the form will be submitted.

See the code below :

```js
function checkPhoneField(element) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let $formElement = $(element).closest("form");
    let isEmpty = true;
    
    $formElement.find("label+input").each(function(){  
        let inputVal = $(this).val();
        if((inputVal != null) && (inputVal != "")){
            isEmpty = false;
            return  false;
        }
    });
    
    if(isEmpty){
        $formElement.find(".text-danger").show();
    }
    else {
        $formElement.submit();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="Get">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label asp-for="HomePhone" class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
            <input asp-for="HomePhone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="(___) ___-____" data-slots="_" />
            <span asp-validation-for="HomePhone" class="text-danger" style="display:none;">msg 1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label asp-for="WorkPhone" class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
            <input asp-for="WorkPhone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="(___) ___-____" data-slots="_" />
            <span asp-validation-for="WorkPhone" class="text-danger" style="display:none;">msg 2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label asp-for="CellPhone" class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
            <input asp-for="CellPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="(___) ___-____" data-slots="_" />
            <span asp-validation-for="CellPhone" class="text-danger" style="display:none;">msg 3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px"  >
        <input style="float: right; margin-bottom:20px" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="checkPhoneField(this)" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with jquery that much. I do have other input fields on my page. Will the above code affect those input fields

Comment: what is the type of your input fields ? 
Can you show me your code or your input fields that you used ?
---------
This code check all the input field that are placed immediately after a label. 
If you have other fields like this that you don't want to check them, then you can add a specific class only for the fields that you want to check (like "field-number"), and you change $formElement.find("label+input")  -->  $formElement.find("input.field-number")